# UPDATE grouping names delimited by ampersand in excel

Tags: excel, grouping, delimiter, names, ampersand

Basically, what I'm trying to do is I have this excel formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND("&",A1,FIND("&",A1))))+1),TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("&",A1,1)+1,FIND("&",A1,FIND("&",A1,1)+1)-FIND("&",A1,1)-1)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)),TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("&",A1)+1,FIND("&",A1)-3)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("&",A1,FIND("&",A1)+1)),CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),",",TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("&",A1,1)+1,FIND("&",A1,FIND("&",A1,1)+1)-FIND("&",A1,1)-1))),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("&", A1)),SUBSTITUTE(A1,MID(A1,FIND(",", A1)+1,FIND(" &", A1)-FIND(",", A1)+2), ""),A1))))
```

if you notice, this part of it:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND("&",A1,FIND("&",A1))))+1)
```

I'm trying to say if the cell contains two commas and two ampersands, then do something. Otherwise, I specify it to do something else. Unfortunately, this condition doesn't behave as expected. Although I have cells with two commas and only a single ampersand:

```
CORNWALL,A ROBERT & CORNWALL,ANNA
```

it treats this as true, and applies the subsequent true statement to the above cell and therefore causes a VALUE error because the subsequent true statement doesn't account for the cell above. It only accounts for cells with two commas and two ampersands. I already have another ISNUMBER condition for the cell above, as you can see in my initial formula.

Is there a way to fix my ISNUMBER condition so in the first level of execution, it checks for both two commas and two ampersands in the cell?

Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I can see what's wrong with your code there, but have you tried a different approach to counting the number of ampersands and commas?

```
=IF(AND(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"&",""))=2,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))=2),TRUECOND,FALSECOND)
```

This just seems a little simpler.